# mb_strposで文字コードを指定したい

Tags: php

```
$s = "あいう";
echo mb_strpos($s, "い");
```

正しければ「１」が出ると思うのですが、出ません。３になってしまいます。
調べたところ、文字コードを指定すれば良いとのことでそのようにしたいのですが、どのようにつければ良いのかわかりません。
どなたかご教授のほど、よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

その場だけ切り抜けたいなら `mb_strpos()` の引数に指定しても構いませんが・・・。

それがソースコードと同じ文字コードなのであれば、他の場所でも使うと思うので [`mbstring.internal_encoding`](http://php.net/manual/ja/mbstring.configuration.php#ini.mbstring.internal-encoding) や [`mb_internal_encoding()`](http://php.net/manual/ja/function.mb-internal-encoding.php) で設定することをお勧めします。

なお、もし `mb_send_mail()` 等を使うのであれば、併せて `mbstring.language` ないし `mb_language()` の設定も必要です。

Answer (score 0):

http://php.net/manual/ja/function.mb-strpos.php

こちらのドキュメントを見てみますと、mb_strposの4番目の引数に文字コードを指定できるようになっているようです。

```
$s = "あいう";
echo mb_strpos($s, "い", 0, "UTF-8");
```

Comment: できました！
もちろんマニュアルの説明も既読していたのですが、自分のコードとは別物で何がなんやら……の状態でした。
解説していただき、ありがとうございました。